# Capturing Inspectors -> WebForms data using FiddlerCore API

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

I wanted to capture the data that is displayed under Inspectors -> WebForms (in Fiddler UI) for each request, using FiddlerCore API, but couldn't find a way to do that.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The data in the `WebForms` tab is carried in the `oSession.fullUrl` and `oSession.requestBodyBytes` array (which should generally be accessed using `oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString()`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eric. I was actually after the header information. I do know that oSession.oRequest.headers would give me the information. However, i have query string parameters in the request header which fiddler splits and displays in Inspectors -> WebForms, however i haven't been able to find a method in fiddlercore api to give me that same result.

Comment: The reason i am looking for a method in fiddlercore api, is because the request headers query string parameters stores url's within it as well, which are displayed in an elegant manner in fiddler (inspectors -> webforms)

Comment: The simplest approach is that you take the `fullUrl` property and put it into a .NET Uri object. Then you call ParseQueryString on it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx